# Initializing class with object in constructor

Tags: c++

My header class looks like-

```
class Dog {
private:
    Owner _owner;

public:

    Dog(Owner o);
    ~Dog();
};
```

Then the part where I receive the error is-

```
Dog::Dog(Owner owner){
    this -> _owner = owner;
}
```

It seems simple but when I compile I get this error and I really don't know why-

`Constructor for 'Dog' must explicitly initialize the member '_owner' which does not have a default constructor`

Any ideas on what I can fix? I'm new to C++ so im guessing that im missing something syntax related

Comment: Use a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Please, don't define anything that starts with `_`. Use trailing `_` instead, if you have to.

Comment: @Cornstalks, the `owner` object has already been initialized in my main method. I'm just passing the data to this class.

Comment: @user3528438: that's a mater of style. There's nothing wrong with it here.

Comment: @Cornstalks In this case, I believe any leading `_` for a name is undefined behavior, since those names are reserved for the compiler. So it's more than an issue of style

Comment: @KABoissonneault: No, those are not reserved and do not cause undefined behavior. Names can start with an `_` so long as: 1) the underscore is not followed by an upper case character or another underscore; or 2) the identifier is not in the global scope. See section 17.4.3.1.2 of the C++ standard.

Comment: @Cornstalks The first restriction seems like a good reason not to use leading underscores. You don't want to accidentally call one of your members _Vptr and get some weird undocumented error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this constructor is called

```
Dog::Dog(Owner owner){
    this -> _owner = owner;
}
```

First the instance variable `_owner` is constructed with its default constructor `Owner()`, then it is assigned with `this -> _owner = owner;.

So you must have a default constructor for this to happen, as your error says, there isn't one available. so you must define it like so and make it public:

```
class Owner {
    public:
    Owner(){ }
};
```

OR
you can simply call the copy constructor `Owner(const Owner& owner)` instead of the default constructor of `Owner()` with

```
Dog::Dog(Owner owner)
 : _owner(owner)
{ }
```

Comment: Once I edited the owner class the error went away. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex I suggest you still do the 2nd solution too. It's the recommended way to initialize members in a constructor